# Does Java have heap and stack?

Tags: java, c++

http://courses.washington.edu/css342/zander/css332/arch.html

bottom of the page:

> The C++ memory model differs from the Java memory model. In C++,
>   memory comes from two places, the run time stack and the memory heap.

This reads as if Java doesnt have a heap (or stack)?

I am trying to learn all the "under the bonnet" details for Java and C++

Comment: That's not really true about C++. There are four storage classes (automatic, static, dynamic, thread-local), but beyond that the implementation is not specified. In Java, it's best to think about "value-semantics" and "reference-semantics" and leave the details to the JVM.

Comment: the link you posted does not say anything about the Java memory model (apart from that it differs from the C++ one).

Comment: @Andre, I know- but saying it's different to C++ and then saying C++ has X and Y suggests Java doesnt have both X and Y

Comment: If you want to learn about Java details, read [The Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/). It's quite accessible. Don't take somebody else's word for it.

Comment: @Greg, I usually post on here asking for book references and then my post gets closed- so I went for the alternative. DO you know an equivalent book/resource for C++?

Comment: @user997112: [The C++ Programming Language](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/3rd.html) by Bjarne Stroustrup. Also, [The Design and Evolution of C++](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/dne.html) is another excellent book.

Answer (score 7):

Java has a heap and a (per-thread) stack as well. The difference is that in Java, you cannot choose where to allocate a variable or object.

Basically, all objects and their instance variables are allocated on the heap, and all method parameters and local variables (just the references in the case of objects) are allocated on the stack.

However, some modern JVMs will allocate some objects on the stack as a performance optimization when they detect that the object is only used locally.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "However, some modern JVMs will allocate some objects on the **stack** as a performance optimization when they detect that the object is only used locally." ?

Comment: Where would a global variable be? Heap?

Comment: @user997112: If you're talking about static fields, those are part of the class object and thus live on the heap.

Comment: @Michael, and non-static globals?

Comment: @user997112: Static fields are the closest thing to global variables Java has. It simply does not *have* variables that are not part of a class (or local).

Answer (score 1):

Java uses a heap memory model.  All objects are created on the heap; references are used to refer to them.

It also puts method frames onto a stack when processing them.

I would say it has both.

Comment: I don't think that's accurate. While internally the JVM does indeed have a stack, it may well decide to put short-lived objects there too if it sees fit and obviate their need for gcollection.

Comment: "may well"?  Please provide a citation for this.  As far as I know, the generational model says that all objects are heap-based, even if an object is created in method scope and is short-lived.  Short lived means eden space on the heap.  If it survives one GC, it goes to generation 1, then generation 2, then perm space.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Java have both heap (common to the entire JVM) and stack (one stack per thread).

And having stack & heap is more a property of implementations than of languages.

I would even say that most Linux programs have heap (obtained thru [`mmap`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) & `sbrk` system calls) and stack (at the level of the operating system, this is not dependent of the language).

What Java have, but C++ usually not, is a [garbage collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29). You don't need to release unused memory in Java. But in C++ you need to release it, by calling `delete`, for every C++ object allocated in the heap with `new`.

See however [Boehm's garbage collector](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/) for a GC usable in C & C++. It works very well in practice (even if it can leak in theory, being a conservative, not a precise, GC).

Some restricted C++ or C environments (in particular free standing implementations for embedded systems without operating system kernel) don't have any heap.